# Context Menu vs Popup

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

What is the difference between a `ContextMenu` class and the `Popup` class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The MSDN docs do a nice job of displaying the distinction:

The [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup) Class:

> Represents a pop-up window that has
>   content.

The [ContextMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contextmenu) Class:

> Represents a pop-up menu that enables
>   a control to expose functionality that
>   is specific to the context of the
>   control.

So the `ContextMenu` is a more-specific version of a `Popup` - it's meant to be bound to a specific control, providing ways to interact with that control. Read further on the MSDN page: the `ContextMenu` has built-in facilities for displaying itself when you right-click on the associated control, and it is automatically displayed *within* a `Popup`.

The `Popup` class is much more general: it simply defines a barebones window (no default borders or decoration) that can display any arbitrary `UIElement` on top of other controls (notice that the `Popup` class is part of the [Primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives) namespace, meaning it's meant to be part of the composition of other controls, such as the `ContextMenu`).